# when applied ssg in next.js 14 not working app/api

Tags: next.js13, app-router, static-site-generation, next.js14

Is there a way to use the API feature of the app router when building with SSG using Next.js version 14? It seems that the code implemented through the API feature is not available when built with SSG. Is there an optimal solution for this situation?

app build next.js static site generation but not working app/api function